# Using componentDidMount() to check user log in status on app load

Tags: reactjs

I am running a React frontend app that checks whether a user is currently logged in on a Rails API. I used componentDidMount to check then set the state accordingly but when the page loads for the first time, and the user is logged in, the required info flashes on the page then the app renders and the state goes back to initial state.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Home from "./Home";
import Header from "./Header";
import Signin from "./Signin";
import Signup from "./Signup";
import { withRouter } from "../withRouter";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loggedInStatus: "NOT_LOGGED_IN",
      user: {},
    };

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
  }


  checkLoginStatus() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/logged_in", { withCredentials: true })
      .then((response) => {
        if (
          response.data.logged_in &&
          this.state.loggedInStatus === "NOT_LOGGED_IN"
        ) {
          this.setState({
            loggedInStatus: "LOGGED_IN",
            user: response.data.user,
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            loggedInStatus: "NOT_LOGGED_IN",
            user: {},
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("check login error", error));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkLoginStatus();
  }

  handleLogin(data) {
    if (data.logged_in) {
      this.setState({
        loggedInStatus: "LOGGED_IN",
        user: data.user,
      });
      this.props.navigate("/");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Header />
        <div className="app container mt-3">
          <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home user={this.state.user.email} />} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route
              path="/signin"
              element={<Signin handleLogin={this.handleLogin} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/signup"
              element={<Signup handleLogin={this.handleLogin} />}
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: Please fill in the rest of the code of the component to understand it. You are setting state in some other function that causes the re-render. 
You can try replacing componentDidMount with componentDidUpdate to ensure the user gets set after the component re-renders. However, you should check where else you set State to see if you're causing the re-render and setting the initial state. ComponentDidMount will not run again after the component re-renders so it's very probable you are setting the initial state somewhere.

Comment: @HogasAndreiMarius I am pasting the code to whole component, I am not setting the state unless a user signs up or sign in which should not trigger on initial page load.

Comment: Strict mode can't automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions: Class component constructor , render , and shouldComponentUpdate methods.

Try to remove strict mode and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: If you could accept my answer that would be great. Thank you and have a beautiful day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strict mode can't automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions: Class component constructor , render , and shouldComponentUpdate methods.

Try to remove strict mode and see if the behavior is the same.